# Regex For replace special character in typescript

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I want to replace the special charecter "?" or "/" from my inner html string. could you suggest the way to do with regex.

Example, I want to replace "?" with " " for below content.

```
"Hello?How are you?<a href="http://hellowaorld?helloworld">hello?world"
```

Answer (score 0):

\? escapes a '?' symbol

the following code would do what you asked

```
myElement.innerHTML = myElement.innnerHTML.replace(/\?/g," ")
```

Comment: from above my question, I just want to replace ? with " " for only the texts not in the <a href="helloworld?world">.

Comment: I just want to display like below, "Hello?How are you?<a href="http://hellowaorld?helloworld">hello?world" this needs to be displayed as  "Hello How are you <a href="http://hellowaorld?helloworld">hello world"